# Apache server gives 403 forbidden error after a couple of request

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403, forbidden

I have a really strange problem.
I am using Apache2 and I have set up a VirtualHost. And it is working, but after a couple of request (4-5), I am getting 403 error.
After I wait 10-20 seconds, the page starts to work again.

Here is my VirtualHost record.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@the-host.com
    ServerName subdomain.the-host.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web

    ErrorLog        /var/log/apache2/subdomain.the-host.com-error.log
    CustomLog       /var/log/apache2/subdomain.the-host.com-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web>
        Options +ExecCGI

        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

The directory has `www-data:www-data` owner ship

Here are the errors from the log

```
[Tue May 21 15:14:57 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:14:58 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:14:58 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web/favicon.ico
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web/favicon.ico
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web/favicon.ico
[Tue May 21 15:14:59 2013] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web/es, referer: http://subdomain.the-host.com/es/leatid
[Tue May 21 15:15:00 2013] [error] [client 111.111.111.111] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/subdomain.the-host.com/current/web/favicon.ico
[Tue May 21 15:15:00 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
[Tue May 21 15:15:00 2013] [warn] [client 111.111.111.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/favicon.ico" (/).
```

Any ideas why apache fails after 4-5 requests?

Comment: What error is posted in the logs?

Comment: I have added the errors to the question

Comment: Define directory index directive .DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml

Comment: Also check for correct directory permissions.

Comment: I have tested it with `DirectoryIndex index.php`, but I get the same error after 5-6 requests and my permissions are `-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data`

Comment: can you try to make your permission to 755 and see if it helps?

Comment: Do you by any chance have mod_security on your server?

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @JennyD: Not that I am aware of (there is no mod_security running `apache2ctl -M`)
@MichaelHampton: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your mod_fcgid backend processes died immediately after request is finished. It's not a normal situation, so you need to find what is the root cause of dying fcgi, maybe some error in a script? I guess it's related to action with /favicon.ico, maybe your script can't handle 404 errors properly or sth like that.